# Can anyone please tell me how can I convert 1M, 1B, 1K to number format in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

Can anyone please tell me how can I convert 1M, 1B, 1K to number format (like 1K = 1000) using formula in excel.

Advance thanks for help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome! Please also specify if your list is limited to only these three designations or would you like to have a universal mechanism for converting MB, MiB, KB, KiB, GB, TiB and [**all the rest**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_information#Systematic_multiples)?

Answer (score 2):

Start with a list of the unit prefixes (e.g. "kMGTPEZYRQ" for SI units), find the last character of the value within that list, convert the found position into the correct power-of-2 or power-of-10 value, multiply with the rest of the value.

For example, "M" ⇒ position **2** ⇒ 1000<sup>**2**</sup> or (10<sup>3</sup>)<sup>2</sup> or 10<sup>(3×**2**)</sup>.

(With binary units it's the same except with 1024<sup>**2**</sup> or 2<sup>(10×**2**)</sup>.)

- For decimal (×1000) SI unit prefixes:

  ```
  =IFERROR(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*POWER(1000,FIND(RIGHT(A1,1),"kMGTPEZYRQ")),A1)
  ```
- For binary (×1024) IEC unit prefixes it's nearly the same:

  ```
  =IFERROR(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*POWER(1024,FIND(RIGHT(A1,1),"kMGTPEZYRQ")),A1)
  ```
- If you need regular orders of magnitude (`B` for "billion"), use `"KMBTQ"` as the list.

  ```
  =IFERROR(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*POWER(1000,FIND(RIGHT(A1,1),"KMBTQ")),A1)
  ```

Comment: That's a really neat solution!